# Best practice for installing node_modules for a reactjs app on Azure Linux Web App

Tags: reactjs, azure, npm, next.js, github-actions

I have a react(specifically NextJS) web app running on a Linux Azure Web App Server. I have it deployed and working correctly via GitHub Actions. However, I'm having issues finding the most efficient way to deploy the node_modules.

Here's what I've tried.

- I've ran the install and build within GitHub Actions and deployed the package as a zip artifact. However, the file was huge due to the node_modules and takes 10+ minutes to deploy.
- I've created a postDeploy script to run after deployment that runs an `npm install`. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it so I reverted this.
- For the startup command, I have azure running `npm run start:prod`. I thought about changing this to `npm install && npm run start:prod` . I'm not sure if this is a good idea either
- What I've settled on so far is I just manually get on the server and run `npm install` after a deployment. This won't work for CI/CD though.

I've read that azure kudu supposedly detects package.json within the wwwroot folder and will automagically install dependencies but I haven't seen this work, nor could I find any documentation on it. So far, my best idea seems to be to change my startup command to run an install before starting the app but I'm not sure.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be a big difference between GitHub Action and Azure DevOps in that terms. But what should you do actually on your pipeline is run `npm run build` command and publish only produced output.

Please take a look [here how it looks on Azure DevOps](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/deploying-react-apps-to-azure-with-azure-devops/).

Comment: Right, in this case, ```npm run build``` is next build, which creates a .next/ folder with the build output. However, we still need the node_modules deployed or installed on the azure server as well.

Comment: It is now possible for next.js to create a standalone deployment folder including only the node_modules needed to run the app - a much smaller deployment package and no need to 'npm install' during deployment - see https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing